# How to convert an array object into object data in a specific format

Tags: javascript, json

Sorry, this is the first time to post a question, if there is something impolite, I will modify it.

I am a programming noob, I am using node.js with mysql.

I got this data in the database:

```
[{"id":230,"a":1,"b":0,"c":0},{"id":232,"a":1,"b":0,"c":0},{"id":234,"a":0,"b":1,"c":0},{"id":236,"a":1,"b":0,"c":0},{"id":238,"a":0,"b":1,"c":0},{"id":240,"a":0,"b":1,"c":0},{"id":242,"a":0,"b":0,"c":1}]
```

This is the format I expect:

```
{"col1":{"a":2},"col2":{"b":1}, "col3":{"a":1},"col4":{"b":2, "c":2} }
```

Only one 1 will appear in the key values of a, b, and c.
It will start from col1. If the value of the next data is different from the previous one, a new col2 will be added. If it is the same, it will be added to the current number of cols.

If c:1 is encountered, no new col is added, it is added to the current col

Here is my code:

```
      let results = [{"id":230,"a":1,"b":0,"c":0},{"id":232,"a":1,"b":0,"c":0},{"id":234,"a":0,"b":1,"c":0},{"id":236,"a":1,"b":0,"c":0},{"id":238,"a":0,"b":1,"c":0},{"id":240,"a":0,"b":1,"c":0},{"id":242,"a":0,"b":0,"c":1}]

      let BigRoad = {
        "col1": {},
        "col2": {},
        "col3": {},
        "col4": {},
        "col5": {},
        "col6": {},
        ..........
        "colN": {},
      }

      for (let i=0; i < results.length; i++) {
        //Loop to the first results. BigRoad.col1 if there is no value, it will match the following two if conditions
        if (results[i].a && Object.keys(BigRoad.col1).length == 0) {
          BigRoad.col1.a = results[i].a
        }
        if (results[i].b && Object.keys(BigRoad.col1).length == 0) {
          BigRoad.col1.b = results[i].b
        }
      }

      console.log(BigRoad)
      //output: { col1: { a: 1 }, col2: {}, col3: {}, col4: {}, col5: {}, col6: {} }
```

I don't know how to use this if method to compose the data I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let results = [{
  "id": 230,
  "a": 1,
  "b": 0,
  "c": 0
}, {
  "id": 232,
  "a": 0,
  "b": 0,
  "c": 0
}, {
  "id": 234,
  "a": 0,
  "b": 1,
  "c": 0
}, {
  "id": 236,
  "a": 1,
  "b": 0,
  "c": 0
}, {
  "id": 238,
  "a": 0,
  "b": 1,
  "c": 0
}, {
  "id": 240,
  "a": 0,
  "b": 1,
  "c": 0
}, {
  "id": 242,
  "a": 0,
  "b": 1,
  "c": 1
}]

let bigRoad = {};
results && results.map((e, i) => {
  for (let x in e) {
    if (x !== 'id') {
      if (e[x]) {
        if (bigRoad.hasOwnProperty(`col${i}`)) {
          bigRoad[`col${i}`][`${x}`] = e[x]
        } else {
          bigRoad[`col${i}`] = {
            [`${x}`]: e[x]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
console.log(bigRoad);
```